# ag-grid Cells with Images and Text using GraphQL

Tags: image, graphql, cell, ag-grid

I'm testing the use of Ag-Grid to see if it will be a good acquisition for my development.

Using vue 2 packages I saw the example of Cells with Images and Text.

However, I use my GraphQL api in the following way to populate the grid:

```
obterImobiliarios() {
            this.$api.query({
                query: gql`{ imobiliarios { idImobiliario inscricaoImobiliario enderecoImobiliario
                    numeroImobiliario bairroImobiliario nomeProprietarioImobiliario  } }`,
                fetchPolicy : 'network-only'
            }).then(resultado => {
                this.imobiliarios = resultado.data.imobiliarios
                this.rowData = resultado.data.imobiliarios
                  this.$store.getters.rowData = resultado.data.imobiliarios 
                this.erros = null
            }).catch(e => {
                this.erros = e
            })
           
        },
```

I have on my server a folder containing images: foto1.png, foto2.png, etcc

If I want the column 'idImobiliario' to show me the text + the corresponding image eg: foto1.png how would it look in the GraphQL api call?

thanks

Solution help using GraphQL with Cells with Images and Text

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly, you get the path to the image with graphQL, an you want ti display image with text in cell?

for that I would develope a **custom cell renderer** that take the path as parameter    and dispay the image and text with classqiue html for example )

hope that help

Comment: Hello,
I get from GrphQL only data in text form. Images are stored in a folder in the directory.

Comment: what you means by "only data in text form" ? how does the client side get the image ?

Comment: Images in .png format are stored on an s3.
The data in the 'inscricaoImobiliario' column contains the link to the example image: https: s3.xxxxxxx.com/foto1.png